# Why people from Marley think once aircraft forces from other nations will be developed , Titans wont be useful anymore?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In one of the chapters of the manga,

> people from Marley think once aircraft forces from other nations will be developed, Titans wont be useful anymore. That there will be aicrafts capable of dropping large bombs and things like that.

But this doesnt happen in our reality, where ground forces are still needed and important.

Why people from Marley think once aircraft forces from other nations will be developed , Titans wont be useful anymore?

Comment: I think that phrase you mentioned answers your question? 'That there will be aicrafts capable of dropping large bombs and things like that.' Titans would have a hard time trying to reach these aircrafts. Not to mention they are faster and harder to bring down than horsemen or foot soldiers.

Comment: But in our reality there are aicrafts capable of dropping large bombs and ground forces are still useful and important. Then?

Comment: Titans aren't the only ground forces Marley has. What Marley is probably saying is that this loses them their advantage since all country fears Marley because of the Titans and because they lead in terms of technology. If even one country gets ahead in terms of aircraft forces, then they lose the Titan advantage they have since it would be harder for Titans to deal with, hence the term 'useless'.

Comment: The tallest titan is about 60m (200ft) whereas airplanes can be flown thousands of feet above the air. This height difference could be exploited and if one nation even gets ahead in terms of aircraft force, then this renders Titans against a fleet of aircraft 'useless'. Not sure how they'd counter that with Titans if it ever happens.